# Interesting MYPY behavior - warning about difflib only once

Tags: python, mypy

I have the following code:

```
"""
FILE:
    diff_tool.py

VERSION:
    .1 - initial file with arguments
    .2 - adding HTML output

DESCRIPTION:
    script that shows the difference between two files.

    https://florian-dahlitz.de/blog/create-your-own-diff-tool-using-python
"""

import difflib
import sys
import argparse

from pathlib import Path
from typing import Union, Iterator

def create_diff(old_file: Path, new_file: Path, output_file: Path=None) -> None:
    file_1 = open(old_file).readlines()
    file_2 = open(new_file).readlines()

    old_name: str = old_file.name
    new_name: str = new_file.name
    delta: Union[str, Iterator[str]] = ""
    if output_file:
        delta = difflib.HtmlDiff().make_file(
            file_1, file_2, old_name, new_name
        )
        with open(output_file, "w") as f:
            f.write(delta)
            f.close()
    else:
        delta = difflib.unified_diff(file_1, file_2, old_name, new_name)
        sys.stdout.writelines(delta)


def main():
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
    parser.add_argument("old_file_version")
    parser.add_argument("new_file_version")
    parser.add_argument("--html", help="specify html to write to")
    args = parser.parse_args()

    old_file = Path(args.old_file_version)
    new_file = Path(args.new_file_version)

    if args.html:
        output_file = Path(args.html)
    else:
        output_file = None

    create_diff(old_file, new_file, output_file)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

I've commented after the else statement the mypy warning which is:

```
Incompatible types in assignment (expression has type "Iterator[str]", variable has type "str")
```

The issue is that the error doesn't show up twice. I know it has to do with the readlines in the file1 and file2 but why doesn't is occur when writing the diff work to an HTML file?

UPDATE: 
I've updated the code but thanks to Samwise defining delta as well cleared up the issue and everything works and no mypy errors. I'm definitely going to start really digging in on typing.

Comment: Where were you expecting the second error?

Comment: I wasn't expecting any error really. And it does run without issue it's just mypy has an issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first time you assign to a variable (in this case `delta`), if you don't provide a type annotation, a type is inferred based on the assigned value.  Subsequent assignments will produce errors if you assign an incompatible type.

So the first assignment doesn't error because it doesn't conflict with anything; the second assignment errors because it conflicts with the first assignment.

Since this value isn't used outside these blocks, I'd recommend just using two different variable names since you have two different types of values.  I.e.:

```
if output_file:
    delta_as_str = difflib.HtmlDiff().make_file(
        file_1, file_2, old_name, new_name
    )
    with open(output_file, "w") as f:
        f.write(delta_as_str)
        f.close()
else:
    delta_as_iter = difflib.unified_diff(file_1, file_2, old_name, new_name)
    sys.stdout.writelines(delta_as_iter)
```

In cases where you do need one variable to potentially contain different types of values, the fix is to declare it as a `Union` type when it's initialized, in order to let mypy know that even though you're giving it a `str` value now, it's valid for it to have an `Iterator[str]` value later:

```
    delta: Union[str, Iterator[str]] = difflib.HtmlDiff().make_file(
        file_1, file_2, old_name, new_name
    )
```

Of course, this means that everything you do with the value after that point has to account for either type!  It's generally better to just have one type per variable so you don't have to do a bunch of `if isinstance...` checks later.

Comment: Well, now I can't write delta  in the if statement where delta is defined.

```
Argument 1 to "write" of "IO" has incompatible type "Union[str, Iterator[str]]"; expected "str"
```

I'm going to look at that one but thanks I knew I had to define delta's type.

Comment: like I said, **use two different variables** instead of trying to do a Union :)  Edited answer to explicitly show how to do this.

Comment: I got it to work using your declaration on delta I just did it before entering the if statement and no more errors.

Comment: You can make it work, but it's really unnecessary pain and it's bad practice IMO to make a variable have wider scope than it needs.  I'd avoid even having this be a named variable, personally.  :)

Comment: Agreed the final version I did exactly that because I was thinking the same exact thing.